# Is there a way to create a new Chrome profile with the help of Selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, profile, google-account, chrome-profile

Is there a way to create a new Chrome profile with the help of Selenium?

Sometimes I am getting the `RPC executor service threw an error!` error message while trying to log into my Google account using Selenium (I am talking about the web Google account, not the account for the Chrome). I think it is related to the profile being used for more than one Selenium test run.

So, I thought that there may be a way to create a new Chrome profile for every Selenium run. I was not able to find it so far though.

I am using C# and here is how I am creating my driver:

`var driver = UndetectedChromeDriver.Instance(null, chromeOptions);`.

So, basically I am using the default `sl_selenium_chrome` profile.

Specifying the arbitrary string instead of the `null` did not help. I.e. changing my code to the:

`var driver = UndetectedChromeDriver.Instance(Guid.NewGuid(), chromeOptions);`

started to open Chrome in my personal profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so like below using Chrome Options, Specify the pat to your Profiles Folder and the New Profile to Create

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        String profileDir="Profile_Test_1";
        // Specify the path to the new profile directory
        options.AddArgument("--profile-directory="+profileDir);
        options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=/Users/achaudhary/Desktop/chromeProfiles/CustomProfile");

        // Instantiate ChromeDriver with the options
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        // Rest of your code...

        // Quit the driver
        driver.Quit();
```

You can see below chrome instance launched with the specified profile
[image]